# Deploy IoT Edge module to a Windows device

Tags: docker, iot, windows-10-iot-core, azure-iot-hub

I am creating IoT Edge using the blog https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart.

I have installed Python 2.7, azure-iot-edge-runtime-ctl on a Windows 1709 Virtual machine.
I am running Docker version 17.09 CE and Windows Containers. When I am trying to setup IoT-edge runtime module in Windows 10 VM.

```
iotedgectl setup --connection-string "{device connection string}" --auto-cert-gen-force-no-passwords
```

when I am running above command facing the issue, Any suggestions appreciated.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
  "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\iotedgectl.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\edgectl\__init__.py", line 25, in coremain
    return cli.execute_user_command()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\edgectl\edgecli.py", line 54, in execute_user_command
    (is_valid, execute_deployment_cmd) = self._process_cli_args()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\edgectl\edgecli.py", line 358, in _process_cli_args
    return args.func(args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\edgectl\edgecli.py", line 379, in _parse_edge_command
    if EdgeDefault.is_deployment_supported(self._deployment):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\edgectl\default.py", line 99, in is_deployment_supported
    client = EdgeDockerClient()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\edgectl\dockerclient.py", line 13, in __init__
    self._client = docker.DockerClient.from_env()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\docker\client.py", line 81, in from_env
    **kwargs_from_env(**kwargs))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\docker\client.py", line 38, in __init__
    self.api = APIClient(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 131, in __init__
    'Install pypiwin32 package to enable npipe:// support'
docker.errors.DockerException: Install pypiwin32 package to enable npipe:// support
```

Any suggestions, please.

Answer (score 4):

**Problem Solution:**

- The “npipe:// broken” problem reported here applicable to Windows machines and is a problem whether Linux or Windows containers are used in Docker.
- [azure-iot-edge-runtime-ctl 1.0.0rc19](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-iot-edge-runtime-ctl) was released recently which addresses this issue by ensuring the correct pypiwin32 package is installed.
- To get the latest bits execute:

  ```
  $> pip install -U azure-iot-edge-runtime-ctl
  ```
- Check installed version:

  ```
  $> iotedgectl --version
  iotedgectl 1.0.0rc19
  ```

**Summary of issue:**

- iotedgectl uses library docker-py to communicate with Docker for kick starting and controlling the Edge runtime.
- docker-py uses pypiwin32 for communicating with docker over named pipes (npipe). With the release of v222 of pypiwin32 docker-py is broken on Windows hosts.
- As a quick workaround until the official fixes can be incorporated, iotedgectl was released which ensures that correctly working dependencies get pulled in.

Answer (score 0):

Is the version of Python you have installed 2.7.14?It seems that pypiwin32 package has not been installed in your PC.Please use `pip` to install this package like executing the following command in your computer:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```